# Fatal Error in my WP "Call to undefined function get_option()"

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, redirect, fatal-error

It all started when I installed the Really Simple plugin on my WordPress website and requested the SSL certificate even though I don't have HTTPS. When I realized this error, it was already too late, and the site stopped working (showing "err_too_many_redirects"). Someone helped me and solved an error but now the website, when I'm trying to log in as admin is showing me this text:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: **Call to undefined function get_option() in /web/htdocs/www.mywebsite.it/home/wp-admin/admin.php:38 Stack trace: #0 /web/htdocs/www.mywebsite.it/home/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /web/htdocs/www.sanvincenzopadova.it/home/wp-admin/admin.php on line 38**

What can I do?

My wp-admin file is this:

```
    <?php
/**
 * WordPress Administration Bootstrap
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Administration
 */

/**
 * In WordPress Administration Screens
 *
 * @since 2.3.2
 */
if ( ! defined( 'WP_ADMIN' ) ) {
    define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );
}

if ( ! defined( 'WP_NETWORK_ADMIN' ) ) {
    define( 'WP_NETWORK_ADMIN', false );
}

if ( ! defined( 'WP_USER_ADMIN' ) ) {
    define( 'WP_USER_ADMIN', false );
}

if ( ! WP_NETWORK_ADMIN && ! WP_USER_ADMIN ) {
    define( 'WP_BLOG_ADMIN', true );
}

if ( isset( $_GET['import'] ) && ! defined( 'WP_LOAD_IMPORTERS' ) ) {
    define( 'WP_LOAD_IMPORTERS', true );
}

require_once dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/wp-load.php';

nocache_headers();

if ( get_option( 'db_upgraded' ) ) {

    flush_rewrite_rules();
    update_option( 'db_upgraded', false );

    /**
     * Fires on the next page load after a successful DB upgrade.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     */
    do_action( 'after_db_upgrade' );

} elseif ( ! wp_doing_ajax() && empty( $_POST )
    && (int) get_option( 'db_version' ) !== $wp_db_version
) {

    if ( ! is_multisite() ) {
        wp_redirect( admin_url( 'upgrade.php?_wp_http_referer=' . urlencode( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) ) );
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Filters whether to attempt to perform the multisite DB upgrade routine.
     *
     * In single site, the user would be redirected to wp-admin/upgrade.php.
     * In multisite, the DB upgrade routine is automatically fired, but only
     * when this filter returns true.
     *
     * If the network is 50 sites or less, it will run every time. Otherwise,
     * it will throttle itself to reduce load.
     *
     * @since MU (3.0.0)
     *
     * @param bool $do_mu_upgrade Whether to perform the Multisite upgrade routine. Default true.
     */
    if ( apply_filters( 'do_mu_upgrade', true ) ) {
        $c = get_blog_count();

        /*
         * If there are 50 or fewer sites, run every time. Otherwise, throttle to reduce load:
         * attempt to do no more than threshold value, with some +/- allowed.
         */
        if ( $c <= 50 || ( $c > 50 && mt_rand( 0, (int) ( $c / 50 ) ) === 1 ) ) {
            require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/http.php';
            $response = wp_remote_get(
                admin_url( 'upgrade.php?step=1' ),
                array(
                    'timeout'     => 120,
                    'httpversion' => '1.1',
                )
            );
            /** This action is documented in wp-admin/network/upgrade.php */
            do_action( 'after_mu_upgrade', $response );
            unset( $response );
        }
        unset( $c );
    }
}

require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/admin.php';

auth_redirect();

// Schedule Trash collection.
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'wp_scheduled_delete' ) && ! wp_installing() ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'wp_scheduled_delete' );
}

// Schedule transient cleanup.
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'delete_expired_transients' ) && ! wp_installing() ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'delete_expired_transients' );
}

set_screen_options();

$date_format = __( 'F j, Y' );
$time_format = __( 'g:i a' );

wp_enqueue_script( 'common' );

/**
 * $pagenow is set in vars.php.
 * $wp_importers is sometimes set in wp-admin/includes/import.php.
 * The remaining variables are imported as globals elsewhere, declared as globals here.
 *
 * @global string $pagenow      The filename of the current screen.
 * @global array  $wp_importers
 * @global string $hook_suffix
 * @global string $plugin_page
 * @global string $typenow      The post type of the current screen.
 * @global string $taxnow       The taxonomy of the current screen.
 */
global $pagenow, $wp_importers, $hook_suffix, $plugin_page, $typenow, $taxnow;

$page_hook = null;

$editing = false;

if ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) {
    $plugin_page = wp_unslash( $_GET['page'] );
    $plugin_page = plugin_basename( $plugin_page );
}

if ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) && post_type_exists( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) ) {
    $typenow = $_REQUEST['post_type'];
} else {
    $typenow = '';
}

if ( isset( $_REQUEST['taxonomy'] ) && taxonomy_exists( $_REQUEST['taxonomy'] ) ) {
    $taxnow = $_REQUEST['taxonomy'];
} else {
    $taxnow = '';
}

if ( WP_NETWORK_ADMIN ) {
    require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/network/menu.php';
} elseif ( WP_USER_ADMIN ) {
    require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/user/menu.php';
} else {
    require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/menu.php';
}

if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    wp_raise_memory_limit( 'admin' );
}

/**
 * Fires as an admin screen or script is being initialized.
 *
 * Note, this does not just run on user-facing admin screens.
 * It runs on admin-ajax.php and admin-post.php as well.
 *
 * This is roughly analogous to the more general {@see 'init'} hook, which fires earlier.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'admin_init' );

if ( isset( $plugin_page ) ) {
    if ( ! empty( $typenow ) ) {
        $the_parent = $pagenow . '?post_type=' . $typenow;
    } else {
        $the_parent = $pagenow;
    }

    $page_hook = get_plugin_page_hook( $plugin_page, $the_parent );
    if ( ! $page_hook ) {
        $page_hook = get_plugin_page_hook( $plugin_page, $plugin_page );

        // Back-compat for plugins using add_management_page().
        if ( empty( $page_hook ) && 'edit.php' === $pagenow && get_plugin_page_hook( $plugin_page, 'tools.php' ) ) {
            // There could be plugin specific params on the URL, so we need the whole query string.
            if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ) ) {
                $query_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            } else {
                $query_string = 'page=' . $plugin_page;
            }
            wp_redirect( admin_url( 'tools.php?' . $query_string ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
    unset( $the_parent );
}

$hook_suffix = '';
if ( isset( $page_hook ) ) {
    $hook_suffix = $page_hook;
} elseif ( isset( $plugin_page ) ) {
    $hook_suffix = $plugin_page;
} elseif ( isset( $pagenow ) ) {
    $hook_suffix = $pagenow;
}

set_current_screen();

// Handle plugin admin pages.
if ( isset( $plugin_page ) ) {
    if ( $page_hook ) {
        /**
         * Fires before a particular screen is loaded.
         *
         * The load-* hook fires in a number of contexts. This hook is for plugin screens
         * where a callback is provided when the screen is registered.
         *
         * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$page_hook`, refers to a mixture of plugin
         * page information including:
         * 1. The page type. If the plugin page is registered as a submenu page, such as for
         *    Settings, the page type would be 'settings'. Otherwise the type is 'toplevel'.
         * 2. A separator of '_page_'.
         * 3. The plugin basename minus the file extension.
         *
         * Together, the three parts form the `$page_hook`. Citing the example above,
         * the hook name used would be 'load-settings_page_pluginbasename'.
         *
         * @see get_plugin_page_hook()
         *
         * @since 2.1.0
         */
        do_action( "load-{$page_hook}" ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidHookName.UseUnderscores
        if ( ! isset( $_GET['noheader'] ) ) {
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php';
        }

        /**
         * Used to call the registered callback for a plugin screen.
         *
         * This hook uses a dynamic hook name, `$page_hook`, which refers to a mixture of plugin
         * page information including:
         * 1. The page type. If the plugin page is registered as a submenu page, such as for
         *    Settings, the page type would be 'settings'. Otherwise the type is 'toplevel'.
         * 2. A separator of '_page_'.
         * 3. The plugin basename minus the file extension.
         *
         * Together, the three parts form the `$page_hook`. Citing the example above,
         * the hook name used would be 'settings_page_pluginbasename'.
         *
         * @see get_plugin_page_hook()
         *
         * @since 1.5.0
         */
        do_action( $page_hook );
    } else {
        if ( validate_file( $plugin_page ) ) {
            wp_die( __( 'Invalid plugin page.' ) );
        }

        if ( ! ( file_exists( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/$plugin_page" ) && is_file( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/$plugin_page" ) )
            && ! ( file_exists( WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR . "/$plugin_page" ) && is_file( WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR . "/$plugin_page" ) )
        ) {
            /* translators: %s: Admin page generated by a plugin. */
            wp_die( sprintf( __( 'Cannot load %s.' ), htmlentities( $plugin_page ) ) );
        }

        /**
         * Fires before a particular screen is loaded.
         *
         * The load-* hook fires in a number of contexts. This hook is for plugin screens
         * where the file to load is directly included, rather than the use of a function.
         *
         * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$plugin_page`, refers to the plugin basename.
         *
         * @see plugin_basename()
         *
         * @since 1.5.0
         */
        do_action( "load-{$plugin_page}" ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidHookName.UseUnderscores

        if ( ! isset( $_GET['noheader'] ) ) {
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php';
        }

        if ( file_exists( WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR . "/$plugin_page" ) ) {
            include WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR . "/$plugin_page";
        } else {
            include WP_PLUGIN_DIR . "/$plugin_page";
        }
    }

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-footer.php';

    exit;
} elseif ( isset( $_GET['import'] ) ) {

    $importer = $_GET['import'];

    if ( ! current_user_can( 'import' ) ) {
        wp_die( __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to import content into this site.' ) );
    }

    if ( validate_file( $importer ) ) {
        wp_redirect( admin_url( 'import.php?invalid=' . $importer ) );
        exit;
    }

    if ( ! isset( $wp_importers[ $importer ] ) || ! is_callable( $wp_importers[ $importer ][2] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( admin_url( 'import.php?invalid=' . $importer ) );
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Fires before an importer screen is loaded.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$importer`, refers to the importer slug.
     *
     * Possible hook names include:
     *
     *  - `load-importer-blogger`
     *  - `load-importer-wpcat2tag`
     *  - `load-importer-livejournal`
     *  - `load-importer-mt`
     *  - `load-importer-rss`
     *  - `load-importer-tumblr`
     *  - `load-importer-wordpress`
     *
     * @since 3.5.0
     */
    do_action( "load-importer-{$importer}" ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidHookName.UseUnderscores

    // Used in the HTML title tag.
    $title        = __( 'Import' );
    $parent_file  = 'tools.php';
    $submenu_file = 'import.php';

    if ( ! isset( $_GET['noheader'] ) ) {
        require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php';
    }

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';

    define( 'WP_IMPORTING', true );

    /**
     * Filters whether to filter imported data through kses on import.
     *
     * Multisite uses this hook to filter all data through kses by default,
     * as a super administrator may be assisting an untrusted user.
     *
     * @since 3.1.0
     *
     * @param bool $force Whether to force data to be filtered through kses. Default false.
     */
    if ( apply_filters( 'force_filtered_html_on_import', false ) ) {
        kses_init_filters();  // Always filter imported data with kses on multisite.
    }

    call_user_func( $wp_importers[ $importer ][2] );

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-footer.php';

    // Make sure rules are flushed.
    flush_rewrite_rules( false );

    exit;
} else {
    /**
     * Fires before a particular screen is loaded.
     *
     * The load-* hook fires in a number of contexts. This hook is for core screens.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$pagenow`, is a global variable
     * referring to the filename of the current screen, such as 'admin.php',
     * 'post-new.php' etc. A complete hook for the latter would be
     * 'load-post-new.php'.
     *
     * @since 2.1.0
     */
    do_action( "load-{$pagenow}" ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidHookName.UseUnderscores

    /*
     * The following hooks are fired to ensure backward compatibility.
     * In all other cases, 'load-' . $pagenow should be used instead.
     */
    if ( 'page' === $typenow ) {
        if ( 'post-new.php' === $pagenow ) {
            do_action( 'load-page-new.php' ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidHookName.UseUnderscores
        } elseif ( 'post.php' === $pagenow ) {
            do_action( 'load-page.php' ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidHookName.UseUnderscores
        }
    } elseif ( 'edit-tags.php' === $pagenow ) {
        if ( 'category' === $taxnow ) {
            do_action( 'load-categories.php' ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidHookName.UseUnderscores
        } elseif ( 'link_category' === $taxnow ) {
            do_action( 'load-edit-link-categories.php' ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidHookName.UseUnderscores
        }
    } elseif ( 'term.php' === $pagenow ) {
        do_action( 'load-edit-tags.php' ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidHookName.UseUnderscores
    }
}

if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ) {
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];

    /**
     * Fires when an 'action' request variable is sent.
     *
     * The dynamic portion of the hook name, `$action`, refers to
     * the action derived from the `GET` or `POST` request.
     *
     * @since 2.6.0
     */
    do_action( "admin_action_{$action}" );
}
```

Comment: Did you uninstall the Really Simple SSL plugin?  Also, using phpMyAdmin, go into your wp_options table and check the main urls for your site, if you can't access wp-admin at all.  Really Simple SSL may have changed your site URLs which has you in a perpetual loop.